# Significance of `@` in Groovy regex

Tags: groovy, jmeter

What is wrong with this code?

```
params = params.replaceAll('@{org}', vars.get('nOrgName_g1'))
```

I get the error:

> Illegal repetition near index 1

If I try:

```
params = params.replaceAll('\@{org}', vars.get('nOrgName_g1'))
```

I get the error:

> Unexpected char: '\'

If I remove this silly piece of text all together, there are no errors.

My variable `params` actually contains the literal `@{org}`. I want to replace it with a variable in JMeter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the `@` but rather the `{}` are special regex repitition symbols and must be escaped:

```
params = params.replaceAll(/@\{org\}/, vars.get('nOrgName_g1'))
```

**Explanation++**

In Groovy a regex literal ('Pattern') is to be represented as `/some.regex/`. In this case, you can easily a use single backslash `\` to escape (special) charachters.

In the literal you can also use Groovy's string interpolation feature, like:

```
String subPatt = '42'
def pattern = /.*($subPatt).*/
```

In methods like `String.replaceAll()` you can also use double (with interpolation) or single (no interpolation) quotes, but in theese cases you will have to insert double backslashes `\\` for escaping:

```
params = params.replaceAll('@\\{org\\}', vars.get('nOrgName_g1'))
```

See [one of many docs](https://e.printstacktrace.blog/groovy-regular-expressions-the-definitive-guide/) for further details

Comment: This works. Thanks for the answer. Can you briefly explain the purpose of the forward slashes and why putting this in single or double-quotes does not work?

Comment: @Appleoddity there are a few different ways to create a string in Groovy, and you are probably familiar with using single quotes (') and double quotes (")... the forward-slash is an alternate syntax, called a Slashy String, used to create a string that doesn't require you to escape backslashes.  It allows you to do this /@\{org\}/ instead of having to do this "@\\{org\\}".  Backslashes are common in regex patterns, so Slashy String are ideal for that.  btw - the forward-slash introduced in the language Perl in the 90's for regex patterns, which is prob where Groovy got the idea from.